# Converting 3 shuffled bytes to two 12bit Integers in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port, byte, bit

I am trying to read data from a serial port using C#.

Normal bytes to ints or floats and bools are not a problem.
However, there is one sequence of 3 bytes that are shuffled and i can't get it to parse properly.

These 3 bytes are representing 2 unsigned 12-bit Integers, one for MainSupplyDC, one for Motor Power.
They are shuffled in a way that it needs reordering before parsing.

My last try ended in something like this, but now i realized again that this can't be correct.

```
    // Main Supply DC
    int MainSupplyDCval = (byte2 >> 4 | byte1);

    // MotorPower
    int MotorPowerVal = (byte3 << 4 | byte2);
```

I don't know how to shift it the right way.

Here is the byte sequence layout:

[image]

same in Text:

```
    Byte1    |         Byte2            |    Byte3
------------------------------------------------------
  Lowbyte    |  4 Lowbit | 4 Highbit    |   Highbyte
MainSupplyDC | MotorPower| MainSupplyDC |  MotorPower
```

Examples of the Byte sequence:

```
E5-00-00
MainSupplyDC expected around 230
MotorPower expected 0

E4-A0-06
MainSupplyDC expected around 230
MotorPower expected about 97

E5-90-0F
MainSupplyDC expected around 230
MotorPower expected about 190
```

Banging my head since 2 days now, just can't get it to work...

**EDIT**

It seems like there are two ways to interpret the given table. In my case @canton7 had the right answer, but i think if the supplier/manufacturer would encode the other way, @dumetrulo would have the correct answer.

Comment: Have you got an example input and corresponding output, so we can tell when we've got it right?

Comment: I expanded the examples section with 3 byte sequences and expected results

Comment: Why do you shift byte2 four positions to the right (`byte2 >> 4`) for MainSupplyDC, when the 4 lower bits of byte2 are supposed the bits 8..12 of the MainSupplyDC value (or buts 7..11, if you prefer zero-based bit positions)? Perhaps it would be a good idea if you visualize the whole bit-shifting thing on paper (graphically as diagram, perhaps); it can help you figuring out comparatively easily how you have to shift and combine the bytes without getting lost...

Comment: In your example "E5-00-00" how is the motor power 18? None of the bits for the motor power are set always resulting in 0

Comment: True, that case would result in 0.

Comment: Your first example really is not making much sense: Given E5-00-00, how could MotorPower ever be about 18? What makes you think it should be 18?

Comment: Yeah I got that one wrong, changing it.

Comment: I guess the examples you give do not account for the division by 10 your code does. Is my guess correct?

Comment: Yes, I'll remove the division in the example since that's for further handling of the data

Comment: Looking closer at your examples, where did you get the values from? Are these values measured with some (multi-)meter, because they are not exactly identical to the 12-bit integers represented by the byte-triplets...

Comment: The bites come from a LIN bus - serial gateway that is attached to a fan. The expected results are optimal values, that's why they are expected not to match exactly.

Comment: By the way, based on your examples given, it seems the bit-order for each byte in the layout table is bit7,bit6,...,bit0 (which is what is usually used in documentation, but unfortunately not always). This should make it easier to parse/understand the layout table correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the two 12-bit values have this structure?

```
MainSupplyDC (low byte) | MainSupplyDC (4 Highbit)
MotorPower (4 lowbit) | MotorPower (Highbyte)
```

In that case:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 0xE4, 0xA0, 0x06 };
int mainSupplyDc = bytes[0] | ((bytes[1] & 0x0F) << 8);
int motorPower = (bytes[1] >> 4) | (bytes[2] << 4);
Console.WriteLine("MainSupplyDC: {0}, MotorPower: {1}", mainSupplyDc, motorPower);
```

Prints:

```
MainSupplyDC: 228, MotorPower: 106
```

Does that look about right?

Comment: I tried your solution and the values seem to be correct. Thank you! I'll mark this as solved.

Comment: Have a look at @dumetrulo's answer as well - he's doing different maths, and getting a slightly different result

Comment: Yeah i just realized that. I will have to dig deeper into what values anre correct and report back.

Comment: I double checked and it seems like the values are within the expected ranges. Dumetrulo's answer produces similar results, but your answer's values are closer to what i'm supposed to have, so i will keep this as the correct answer. I think in the end it depends on the bit layout and if i understand it correctly the table given to me is not 100% percent clear on how to read the values.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the table correctly, the following method should do the trick:

```
public static (int, int)
Get12BitValues(byte d1, byte d2, byte d3) =>
    ((int)d1 | ((int)d2 >> 4),
    ((int)d3 << 4) | ((int)d2 & 0x0f));
```

Then your two values will be obtained as follows:

```
var (v1, v2) = Get12BitValues(byte1, byte2, byte3);
float MainSupplyDCval = (float)v1 / 10.0f;
float MotorPowerVal = (float)v2 / 10.0f;
```

Comment: Thank you, i think your solution works also, but i'm stuck on an older C# version, so i have to go with canton7's answer.

Comment: @Heilandzack I don't think this is the same solution as mine - they produce similar results, and they're both based on the same table, but I don't think they're the same. You probably want to check them both against other input/output values before deciding which is correct.

Comment: For MainPowerSupply, how is shifting D2 4 bits to the right producing bit 7..11 for the 12 bit value? What kind of magic is that?

Comment: @elgonzo you're right, that can't possibly be right.

Comment: Pulling MotorPowerVal bits out of the lower 4 bits of d2 is surely wrong as well? The table says it's the higher 4 bits

Comment: Yeah, looking at the examples, the "4 low-bit MotorPower" are provided by the higher 4 bits of D2. Based on the examples given, the bit-order used in the layout table is bit7,bit6,...,bit0.

Comment: If i could i would mark this as a second correct answer, as it also produces good results. However in this case it seems the bits are layed out in a way that @canton7 has given the right way to convert as his result is closer to my expected values.